# Blazor in Firefox shows blank page when render-mode=Server

Tags: firefox, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

1. Using Visual Studio 2019. Create a new *Blazor Server App* (**using .NET 5.0**).
2. In `_Host.cshtml` file set:

`<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />`

It will not render in Firefox, it just shows a blank page.

I came across this while trying to troubleshoot another problem I'm having. Is this a known bug?

---

*Update*: Performed these steps using *.NET Core 3.1* and it *works*. I didn't think it would matter but I tried it anyway. Now what? I have to use .NET 5. Is this a known problem?

I started this investigation because my app started not working properly in Firefox.

---

*Update*: I get this error message in the console: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'import' 1 blazor.server.js:1:67825`. I get errors using Core 3.1 too (still works though), but not this one. Maybe this is the reason. I tried googling it but didn't find anything.

Comment: Blazor server can work on .net 5 with Firefox.  Did you check Firefox's console for error messages?

Comment: @JasonD Yes, I get this error message in the console: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'import' 1 blazor.server.js:1:67825`. I get errors using Core 3.1 too (still works though), but not this one.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: @JasonD 56.0 64-bit

Comment: That looks pretty old.  Maybe try updating and see if that helps.

Comment: @JasonD I thought I did update it this morning. I went into Help->About and clicked update and it restarted. I assumed it was up-to-date. I swear I even did it a second time today. I did it again just now and it updated and restarted. Now it says it's up-to-date. It must have required incremental upgrades. I don't use Firefox much. So now it "works" but the styling is fubar'd.

Comment: Glad it's working for you.  Try <Ctrl>+F5 to refresh the cache.  It may help with the styling.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox wasn't up-to-date. See my comment for an explanation.